# How to show opening amount in bills receivable report in xml format using tally?

Tags: tally

I am trying to get Tally Erp 9 Bills Receivable through post XML Request, everything is working fine except opening amount. Please guide me to get opening amount.

XML Request:

```
     <ENVELOPE>

        <HEADER>
            <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
        </HEADER>

        <BODY>
            <EXPORTDATA>
                <REQUESTDESC>

                    <STATICVARIABLES>
                        <SVEXPORTFORMAT>SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                    </STATICVARIABLES>

                    <REPORTNAME>Bills Receivable</REPORTNAME>

                </REQUESTDESC>
            </EXPORTDATA>
        </BODY>
            
    </ENVELOPE>
```

XML Response:

```
    <ENVELOPE>
    <BILLFIXED>
    <BILLDATE>1-Dec-2016</BILLDATE>
    <BILLREF>A-2602</BILLREF>
    <BILLPARTY>ABC Company</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLCL>-17000.00</BILLCL>
    <BILLPDC></BILLPDC>
    <BILLFINAL>-17000.00</BILLFINAL>
    <BILLDUE>31-Dec-2016</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>1848</BILLOVERDUE>
    <BILLFIXED>
    <BILLDATE>15-Dec-2016</BILLDATE>
    <BILLREF>A-2726</BILLREF>
    <BILLPARTY>XYZ Company</BILLPARTY>
    </BILLFIXED>
    <BILLCL>-74400.00</BILLCL>
    <BILLPDC></BILLPDC>
    <BILLFINAL>-74400.00</BILLFINAL>
    <BILLDUE></BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>1834</BILLOVERDUE>
    </ENVELOPE>
```

Expected XML Response:

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <BILLFIXED>
    <BILLDATE>1-Dec-2016</BILLDATE>
    <BILLREF>A-2602</BILLREF>
    <BILLPARTY>ABC Company</BILLPARTY>
</BILLFIXED>
    <BILLOP>-17000.00</BILLOP>
    <BILLCL>-17000.00</BILLCL>
    <BILLPDC></BILLPDC>
    <BILLFINAL>-17000.00</BILLFINAL>
    <BILLDUE>31-Dec-2016</BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>1848</BILLOVERDUE>
    <BILLFIXED>
    <BILLDATE>15-Dec-2016</BILLDATE>
    <BILLREF>A-2726</BILLREF>
    <BILLPARTY>XYZ Company</BILLPARTY>
</BILLFIXED>
    <BILLOP>-90000.00</BILLOP>
    <BILLCL>-74400.00</BILLCL>
    <BILLPDC></BILLPDC>
    <BILLFINAL>-74400.00</BILLFINAL>
    <BILLDUE></BILLDUE>
    <BILLOVERDUE>1834</BILLOVERDUE>
</ENVELOPE>
```

How to get Tally Erp 9 Bills Receivable through post XML Request with opening amount? Is there is any option to set `Show Opening Amount: Yes` in XML Request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the report and Add  `<SET>ShowOpBillAmt:Yes </SET>`

Full XML will be

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>DATA</TYPE>
        <ID>CustBillsreceivable</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <REPORT ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CustBillsreceivable">
                        <USE>Bills Receivable  </USE>
                        <SET>ShowOpBillAmt:Yes </SET>
                    </REPORT>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```